# Jquery datepicker: How to populate altField with a custom value like (current date 30 days)

Tags: uidatepicker

I have to create a Date Range Control using Jquery datepicker.

There are two date pickers. FromDt and EndDt

I am trying to set the value of  EndDt by using altField as FromDt.Val()+30 
and same approach for FromDt...
this will be FromDt.Val()-30.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to set a date field value based on the selection of another date using jQuery datepicker. In this example, the the end date is auto populated and set to 30 days after the date that was selected.

```
 <input id="startdate" type="text" class="datepicker"  />
 <input id="enddate" type="text" readonly="readonly" />

$('input[id="startdate"]').datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        var start = $('#startdate').val();
        var nights = 30;
        var date = new Date(start);
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var edate = new Date(y, m, d + nights);
        var test = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', edate);
        $('#enddate').val(test);
    }
});
```

This should set you on the right path.